# Normalized data in google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

In the case where you are grouping by say an employee, how do you manage duplicates?  If say both employees 123 and 456 are both named "John Smith" and EmployeeName is used as the break down dimension how do I make them both show up separately?

I know I could make this a concern of the ETL to the data warehouse and append a "(2)" to one of the EmployeeNames.  But is there a mechanism in data studio to use semi normalized data for dimensions and somehow use EmployeeId as the breakdown dimension, but then still use EmployeeName for what is displayed?  Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You can create calculated field, which combines both ID and name. E.g.:

```
CONCAT(Name, " (" , Id, ")")
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear that I'm trying to avoid that - our IDs are large and will really muddy up the legend of a graph.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid there is no other solution.